Type cannot be used to index type on third level property
I'm having an issue with a third-level property typing on a constant. The below code is the minimal code I was able to use to recreate the issue:
interface ActorOptionSection<K extends string = string> {
  key: K;
}

interface ActorOption<K extends string = string> {
  key: K;
  sections: Record<string, ActorOptionSection<string>>;
}

interface Actor<K extends string = string> {
  key: K;
  options: Record<string, ActorOption<string>>;
}

const ActorMap = {
  alice: {
    key: "alice",
    options: {
      optA1: {
        key: "optA1",
        sections: {
          sectionA11: {
            key: "sectionA11"
          }
        }
      },
      optA2: {
        key: "optA2",
        sections: {
          sectionA21: {
            key: "sectionA21"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  bob: {
    key: "bob",
    options: {
      optB1: {
        key: "optB1",
        sections: {
          sectionB11: {
            key: "sectionB11",
          }
        }
      },
      optB2: {
        key: "optB2",
        sections: {
          sectionB21: {
            key: "sectionB21",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} as const satisfies Record<string, Actor<string>>;

type TypeOfMap = typeof ActorMap;
type ActorKey = keyof typeof ActorMap;
type SelectedActor<T extends ActorKey> = TypeOfMap[T];
type SelectedActorOptions<T extends ActorKey> = SelectedActor<T>["options"];
type KeyOfSelectedActorOptions<T extends ActorKey> = keyof SelectedActorOptions<T>;
type SelectedActorSelectedOption<T extends ActorKey, O extends KeyOfSelectedActorOptions<T>> = SelectedActorOptions<T>[O];
type SelectedActorSelectedOptionSections<T extends ActorKey, O extends KeyOfSelectedActorOptions<T>> = SelectedActorSelectedOption<T, O>["sections"]
// Unexpected error: Type '"sections"' cannot be used to index type 'SelectedActorSelectedOption<T, O>'.(2536)


// No error (as expected)
const aliceOptA1Sections: SelectedActorSelectedOptionSections<"alice", "optA1"> = { sectionA11: { key: "sectionA11" } };

// Error (as expected): Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'sectionA11' does not exist in type '{ readonly sectionA21: { readonly key: "sectionA21"; }; }'. Did you mean to write 'sectionA21'?(2561)
const aliceOptA2Sections: SelectedActorSelectedOptionSections<"alice", "optA2"> = { sectionA11: { key: "sectionA11" } };

see playground
the above is a simplified version of the original issue as I split the type building into several steps, where I'm getting the error on the last step (SelectedActorSelectedOptionSections).
Although I'm getting an error on the last step, using it still works.
What am I missing? how do I get it to not error out?

See the linked q/a for more info. You could work around it as shown there, like this for your example code.

@jcalz hats off to you!
